# Заполненные формы c переменным числом полей

Tags: django

Привет, опять нужна помощь по Django.

Вот так описывается класс с фиксированным числом полей:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    url = forms.CharField()

form = ContactForm({'name': 'Your name', 'url': 'http://'})
```

А мне нужно сгенерить форму с заранее неизвестным числом полей(из базы).
Как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете генерировать поля динамически при помощи ModelForm Factory
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function

Comment: Спасибо попробую